# Repository And Unit Of Work : Entity no loading based on foreign key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using Repository and Unit of Work Pattern and my classes are as follows

> CourseInstructor Entity

```
[Serializable]
public class CourseInstructor : AuditableEntity
{        
    #region Primitive Properties
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CourseID is required.")]
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "StudentID is required.")]
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Person Student { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

> Person Entity

```
[Serializable]
public class Person : AuditableEntity
{
    #region Primitive Properties
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastName is required."), StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "LastName is too long!")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FirstName is required."), StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "FirstName is too long!")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "HireDate is required.")]
    public DateTime? HireDate{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EnrollmentDate is required.")]
    public DateTime? EnrollmentDate{ get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<CourseInstructor> CourseInstructor{ get; set; }
    //Have other navigation properties to some other entities

    #endregion
}
```

> Course Entity

```
[Serializable]
public class Course : AuditableEntity
{
    #region Primitive Properties
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required."), StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Title is too long!")]
    public string Title
    {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Credits is required.")]
    public int Credits
    {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "DepartmentID is required.")]
    public int DepartmentID
    {get;set;}
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public Department Department { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<OnlineCourse> OnlineCourses
    {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<OnsiteCourse> OnsiteCourses
    {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<StudentGrade> CourseStudentGrades
    {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<CourseInstructor> CourseInstructor
    {get;set;}
    #endregion
}
```

> CourseInstructorConfig

```
public class CourseInstructorConfig : MyProjectConfig<CourseInstructor>
{
    public CourseInstructorConfig()
    {       
        base.HasRequired<Course>((CourseInstructor a) => a.Course)
           .WithMany((Course c) => c.CourseInstructor)
           .HasForeignKey<int>((CourseInstructor d) => d.CourseID);

        base.HasRequired<Person>((CourseInstructor w) => w.Student)
          .WithMany((Person p) => p.CourseInstructor)
          .HasForeignKey<int>((CourseInstructor q) => q.PersonID);
    }
}
```

> CourseConfig

```
public class CourseConfig : MyProjectConfig<Course>
{
    public CourseConfig()
    {
        base.HasRequired<Department>((Course c) => c.Department)
            .WithMany((Department d) => d.Courses)
            .HasForeignKey<int>((Course cs) => cs.DepartmentID);            
    }
}
```

> CourseInstructorManager

```
public class CourseInstructorManager
{
    public static List<CourseInstructor> GetCourseInstructor()
    {
        return new CourseInstructorRepository().GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

When I am trying to get the data of CourseInstructor, I am getting value of Course as null also value of Student as null. Can anybody tell me what is the problem in above code? Or should I do any corrections or additions? How can I brong those entitites filles

```
List<CourseInstructor> c = CourseInstructorManager.GetCourseInstructor();
Course co = c[0].Course;
Person p = c[0].Student;
```

[image]

co and p both are null.

Comment: You are not supposed to paste huge codes here. If your question is too long, you will hardly get an answer. But first thing which comes in my mind is that you disabled *LazyLoading*. Look at [example about loading related entities](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/4678/loading-related-entities#t=201610130557286924715) and try to load your entities with one of these options.

Comment: To get the clear understanding complete code was required. I have pasted only basic classes over here..

Comment: @AdilMammadov if you look at the actual code pasted, **LazyLoading** is enabled.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, didn't expected that it to be in the `OnModelCreating`. As far as I know, this method is called once, so it can easily be disabled on the other place

Answer (score 1):

You should use virtual keyword, when you want to load data with lazy loading. So your `CourseInstructor`shoul be

```
public class CourseInstructor : AuditableEntity
{        

   #region Primitive Properties
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "CourseID is required.")]
   [ForeignKey("Course")]
   public int CourseID { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "StudentID is required.")]
   [ForeignKey("Student")]
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   #endregion

   #region Navigation Properties

   public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
   public virtual Person Student { get; set; }
   #endregion 
}
```

Useful article about this: [Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx)